# jMock What is Context

Tags: java, jmock

Reading a jmock docs i see:

> First we must import the jMock classes, define our test fixture class and create a "Mockery" that represents the context in which the Publisher exists. The context mocks out the objects that the Publisher collaborates with (in this case a Subscriber) and checks that they are used correctly during the test.

I like to know what mean "context in which the Publisher exists", this is a scope of the class or something like?

Answer (score 1):

It's overly formal language, it's only saying that the `Mockery` holds the record of all of the mock objects under test at any given time. In 99% of cases, each test case has one `Mockery`, and therefore the test case *is* the context.

The language used in that part of the docs seems more appropriate if you're thinking from the point of view of how JMock is designed internally, rather than as a writer of unit tests.

Comment: There may only be one JMock context per test class (although that's not a formal requirement), but there may be other contexts within a test. It's taken all the way to JUnit 4 to be able to distinguish the context of the test from what goes on inside it. Usually they're aligned, but just occasionally it really matters.